# Looking for similar kind of implantation which I have given into C#

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays

```
const unique = array.map(item => item.age).filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index)
```

Does anyone know the similar kind of implementation in C#?

Comment: You're looking for [Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/).

Comment: var unique = array.DistinctBy(s => s.age).ToArray();      - this particular line will return the distinct value of age but In my implementation "array" is on of the element of another Array. I find difficult to do that implementation

Comment: `.Select(x => x.age)` is what you are missing to get the result in just ages.